# searchBar‘s frame changed after clicked cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, frame, searchbar

I add my searchBar(left) and a button(right) as subViews to a UIView.Then set the UIView as the TableHeaderView.But after I end searching and click the cancel button back to the tableview,the searchBar will totally cover the tableHeaderView and can't see the button added.And I viewed the layer,the button still there,just covered by the expanding searchbar.Anyone know how to resolve this?Thanks in advance!

```
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WinWidth, 40)]; 
self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WinWidth-50, 40); 
UIButton *filterBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(WinWidth-30, 10, 20, 20)];

 filterBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_expend_down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar]; [self.searchController.searchBar addSubview:filterBtn]; 
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [self colorWithRGB:0xf2f2f2 alpha:1]; 
[view addSubview:filterBtn];
 view.backgroundColor =self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor; self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;
```

Comment: share some code

Comment: Code like:
```self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;  
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WinWidth, 40)];  
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, WinWidth-50, 40);  
    UIButton *filterBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(WinWidth-30, 10, 20, 20)];
```

Comment: and:
```[filterBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow_expend_down"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
    [view addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
    [self.searchController.searchBar addSubview:filterBtn];
    self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [self colorWithRGB:0xf2f2f2 alpha:1];
    [view addSubview:filterBtn];
    view.backgroundColor =self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = view;```

Comment: Sorry for in a mess.

Comment: update your question

Answer (score 0):

try adding :    tableView.tableHeaderView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

Comment: Tried but doesn't work,I thank when click the cancel button the delegate method or something else change the searchBar's frame ,but  I can't find in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

Comment: It seems doesn't make a sense,button still hided by the searchBar